# To display image in ImageView where drawable image ids stored in database column using Picasso

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, picasso

I am using Picasso to set image into `ImageView` from database where I have stored the drawable image id in the database. It is working perfectly when I store URL(eg https://loremflickr.com/g/320/240/paris)but it's not working for (eg R.drawable.team).
[database image]

```
        //image is the database column containing image ids
        Context context = imageText.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(image)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .resize(50, 50)
                .into(imageview);
```

Comment: Try with simply use "R.drawable.your_image_id", without the use of Picasso.

Comment: but i have multiple images and its need to work dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You to pass the path of the image to set image.Use Glide library to set image it is easy and have more functionality than picasso

Comment: Thanks can you help me with it. i am new to android

Answer (score 0):

Picasso is only a library that makes rendering the image easier through the uri or url path, without picasso you have to create an asyncronous script that is quite complicated. But if you have dynamic data for your drawing path, you can do it with regular looping.
They are now supporting loading Image from URI like the following :

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.get().load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

From [picasso v2+](http://square.github.io/picasso/) here is a big modification. The new version is very helpful for manage cash data. It's using Singleton Instance.

By the way, please don't save the drawable ID, just store the drawable name so that later when you call it use the method like the following

```
private void loadImage(String mImageName, ImageView mImageIcon){
int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(mImageName , "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
            if(resID!=0) {//The associated resource identifier. Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)
                mImageIcon.setImageResource(resID);
            }
}
```

Comment: Its doesn't seem to work. can you help me with my own method i have mentioned above.when i give the drawable id in the load() its perfectly working but when i store those ids in database and give the column name inside load() its not doing anything.@Nanda Z

Comment: As i said before, if you keep using id of drawable to store database it might cause crash or NullReference. Better use drawable's name instead. If error happened could you show it here please.

Comment: right, I hope the name is unique so it will be better

Comment: Thank you so much @Nanda Z. it worked perfectly.just the one i wanted it to do.

Comment: I recommend not to save large files in the project. This will affect the size of your apk. Use Url and do readStream. If the answer is correct, please provide a checklist or upvote :)